# Fetch data from an URL like this: "http://192.168.1.25/$TEXT" on an iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an iOS application where many devices, much more than seven, shall send text to my iPad via a private WiFi network. I want to do this as easy as possible, without security, i.e. sending the TEXT to my iPad on "IP 192.168.1.25"  in this way "http://192.168.1.25/$TEXT". (The IP address will change each time i log on to WIFI, but I´ll take care of that in my solution.)

I want to let my iPad listen to its own IP-address for about 30 seconds for incoming data and in this period the text must be saved in an array. 
After 30 seconds the iPad will stop listening and then start analyzing the received text that was saved in the array.

Hope that someone can help me! Thank You.

Comment: You need to open a Web sever in your application, and need to listen all incoming request. You can make use of this link : https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer.

Comment: Thanks, but I´m not sure how to do this, so I hope you can help me ...  I have several ´clients´ having iPhones and other phones, and one iPad master. The iPad sends out questions to all the phones on my private network (WiFi). Then the phones shall answer the questions and then send the answers back to the iPad. The iPad sends a new question ... and so on..  How can I do this?

Comment: I´m now using a HTTP-server and my app is working!   :-) Thank you very much!